# c# access System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-update

When i write this code i'm taking

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
>   message.(c#, access(SayacGun, SayacToplam are integers and Tarih is dateTime))

```
OleDbConnection dbBaglanti2 = new OleDbConnection(VTYolu);
dbBaglanti2.Open();
string Ekle2 = "UPDATE Sys_Sayac SET SayacGun = @Gun, SayacToplam = @Toplam, WHERE Tarih = @Tarih";
OleDbCommand Komut2 = new OleDbCommand(Ekle2, dbBaglanti2);
Komut2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gun", int.Parse(OkunanGun));
Komut2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Toplam", Convert.ToInt32(OkunanToplam) + 1);
Komut2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarih", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
Komut2.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbBaglanti.Close();
```

Comment: DateTime.Now contains also the seconds. Very improbable that you can find a record with that condition. And when you transform a date in a string then anything can happen there. also that you update the wrong records. Use parameters of type DateTime and forget about AddWithValue.

Comment: If `tarih` is `DateTime` than remove `ToShortDateString`. I have to remember "dbBaglanti". "Did you open your baglanti?"

Comment: Can you give me an example @Steve. Thansk.

Comment: Thanks @T.S. i correct it.

Comment: If the field _Tarih_ is of type DateTime on the DataBase then you don't use a string to query on it but a real DateTime otherwise any kind of wrong conversion could happen. Second, if the field contains only Dates with time always zero, using now will work only when Now is midnight. If instead it contains also the Time part then you need to use a range >= and <= to search for records not Now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the comma "," before the WHERE clause,

```
string Ekle2 = "UPDATE Sys_Sayac SET SayacGun = @Gun, SayacToplam = @Toplam WHERE Tarih = @Tarih";
```

For more information check details of update syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql)

Comment: After working 18hours. my brain has died. I spend 3 hour for a comma ",". I will kill it. Thanks a lot @4D1C70.